# Codigo em C só compila uma vez e depois fecha

Tags: c, struct, return

Tenho um código que estou escrevendo em C, e aí um problema esta constantemente acontecendo. Não sei se tem algo a ver com alocação de memoria.

Possuo uma função:

```
struct elementodos interpretar(char* element){

    struct elementodos separado;
    char** pontpont = (char**)malloc(200 * sizeof(char*));

    int i, a, cont, tem[100], cdd, dll, obs,conta,jubs, xevs;
    int mult[100];
    char* brasil = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    char* bahea = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    char** elemfim = (char**)malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));
    char* zoia = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

...

for (i=0;i<cont;i++){

        separado.multidor[i]=mult[i];
        separado.cadaum[i]=elemfim[i];

    }
    separado.numero=cont;

return separado;
}
```

Os elementos  estão todos definidos:

```
struct elementodos{
    int multidor[100];
    int numero;
    char** cadaum[100];
};
```

Assim eu chamo a função no meu main:

```
int main(){
struct elementodos a; 
...

a= interpretar(b);
return 0;
```

O problema e que isso executa perfeitamente na primeira vez,porém, na segunda ele dá *crash* no prompt comando.

Ps: Não retorna nenhum erro.

Quando rodo o debugger unica coisa que aparece e:

> ```
> In _Jv_RegisterClasses () ()
> In _Jv_RegisterClasses () ()
> [Inferior 1 (process 4184) exited normally]
> Debugger finished with status 0
> ```

Comment: Você já tentou utilizar o GDB para rodar linha a linha? De qualquer forma algumas coisas me parecem estranhas, ele parece se aproveitar de lixos de memória para rodar na primeira, e não tem a mesma sorte na segunda em diante. E este código também não esta completo, poste todo o código, principalmente onde você atribui valores a `cont`,`mult` e a `elemfim`.